# Buttons appearing in upper left corner with different look and feel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm trying to add Tiny Look and Feel to my Java Code. I am using NetBeans IDE form designer and I added TinyLaf as it's UI Manager. But whenever I compile my program, something's wrong appears on the top left corner of my frame. The last button I hovered my mouse will appear on the top left corner of the screen (just the image of it; not the whole button).

Something's wrong in JFrame with different Look and Feel :-

[image]

I followed the instructions from the TinyLaf Documentation:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(true);
System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.muntjak.tinylookandfeel.TinyLookAndFeel");
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I also added TinyLaf on the libraries in my NetBeans project. But still, that image appeared on screen.
What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates how you had the button to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I am unable to reproduce your problem and I agree with [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr): please provide more code and other essential information. Which version of TinyLaF are you using (I have tried TinyLaF 1.4.0 from [muntjak.de/hans/java/tinylaf](http://www.muntjak.de/hans/java/tinylaf/index.html))? Do you use a specific theme? Which version of NetBeans are you working with? What form definition file(s) are you using? Which layout manager have you used to place the button on the form?

If you provide more information, you enable people to help you further instead of having to guess for details about your project. When we can reproduce your problem, we can search for a solution more quickly. Please extend your question: we are happy to help.

A quick attempt at some code using TinyLaF is shown here below (without NetBeans and also without the issue you described):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TinyLafButtonOnFrame {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        new TinyLafButtonOnFrame().launchGui();
    }

    private void launchGui() {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(true);
        System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.muntjak.tinylookandfeel.TinyLookAndFeel");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new JButton("btn1"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I tried your code but unfortunately the same thing happened to me. When I click any of the control buttons (min, max, close), it still display the control button on the top left corner of the frame. I am using TinyLaF 1.4.0 from the TinyLaF website you linked.

Comment: Do you use a specific TinyLaF theme? Which version of NetBeans are you working with? What form definition file(s) are you using? Which layout manager have you used to place the button on the form?

Comment: Yes. I set the nightly theme as the default theme. I am using NetBeans 8.0.2. What are form definition files? I used the default layout manager (free form) of NetBeans to arrange things in my Form.

Comment: So you run into the problem when you click on the window control buttons in the top right corner of the frame? Can you make a screenshot of the problem when it occurs with the code in this answer? I am still unable to make it happen on my system (Windows 8.1, Java 1.8.0_65, IntelliJ IDEA 15). What operating system and which version of Java do you use?